# All Entry inputs are red when selected

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Whenever I tap on a entry component  while debugging the color when selected is red. I have not set this anywhere so I don't understand why this is happening.
My resource file has this for the color of "TextColor"

```
    <Color x:Key="TextColor">#FFFFFF</Color>
```

My Xaml for page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Views.RegisterPage"
                      BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}">
<ContentPage.Content>

    <FlexLayout Direction="Column" Margin="30" 
            JustifyContent="Center" >
        <StackLayout Margin ="0,0,0,15">
            <Entry  PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" Placeholder="First Name"/>
            <Entry PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" Placeholder="Last Name "  />
            <Entry PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" Placeholder="E-Mail " />
            <Entry PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" Placeholder="Password" />
            <Entry PlaceholderColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" Placeholder="Retype Password" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Margin ="0,30,0,0">
            <Button TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AccentColor}" Padding="20" Text="Register"/>

        </StackLayout>

    </FlexLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

How it looks
 [image: The Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular color in android represents the Accent Color. You can override android styles for accent color to define that color.

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">#your-color-here </item>
</style>

</resources>
```

You should be able to find Styles.xml file in your Xamarin Android Specific project inside resources folder. Hope this helps.

**Note** : This will change the accent color of other controls as well. If you only want to change such color for Entry only. You have to write the Custom Renderer for that. Let me know If you want to go that way.

Comment: Just to add to that, have a look at the [google docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#CustomizeTheme) on these theme colors

Comment: I found it , in my android file there is a styles.xml file. Ive added it in but it does not work.